# Common meeting point for 3 points to reach 4th point

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

Problem statement: We are 3 friends at 3 different locations $A, B, C$ and want to reach a location $D$. Each person will take a separate cab to a common meeting point $E$, and then take a single cab from $E$ to $D$.

How can I find the point $E$ which minimizes the total distance traveled by all four cabs?

Comment: Your problem isn't very well defined and some users of this site will take issue with that. People $A$, $B$, and $C$ need to reach a point in how similar of a time? What is the relative importance of them meeting close to $D$ versus minimizing the distance traveled by each person?

Comment: They all have to reach a point X which is close to D, so that all of them have to travel least.

Comment: But if you want to minimize the distances that each person travels, they should just go straight to $D$.

Comment: sorry my bad completely, was in between and wrote the above comment. Basically, think of a scenario where they all are taking cabs and I want to minimize the cost of cabs they are taking. Which depends on number of cabs and time they are travelling. I want to minimize, (number of cabs + time for each of them) by making them travel some distance in separate cabs and then taking one single cab. Sorry about the above comment.

Comment: @amitchhajer I've taken a stab at clarifying the problem statement to reflect the problem you intended to ask. Please edit again if I got something wrong.

Comment: Are there any limits to the paths taken by the cabs?  Must they travel along a grid of streets?  Or can they travel on any straight path?

Answer (score 3):

If $E$ is the common meeting point, you are trying to solve

$$\min_E \|A-E\| + \|B-E\| + \|C-E\| + \|D-E\|$$

The solution to this optimization problem is the *[geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median)* $E$ of the three friends and the destination point $D$. In general computing the geometric median is not straightforward, but in the special case of four points there is an easy algorithm:

1) If one of the four points lies in the triangle formed by the others, take $E$ to be that point. In this case all friends travel directly to $D$ (if this is the inside point) or two friends first travel to the third and then all friends travel together to $D$.

2) Otherwise, the four points form a quadrilateral. Draw the diagonals and take $E$ to be the intersection point.

It's not so obvious why this algorithm correctly identifies the median; proofs are given [here](http://mosi.vub.ac.be/papers/Plastria2005_Fegnano.pdf).